# How can I sort this hash with an array as a value?

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash

```
{"f"=>[0, 1], "i"=>[1, 2], "n"=>[2, 2], "d"=>[3, 1], "g"=>[6, 1]}
```

I ultimately want to grab this value out of it `"i"=>[1, 2]`. I want to grab this value because the logic is that out of all these characters in some string, `i` has the highest value of occurrences `2` but appears first in a string given by its index in the array `1.`

So for a string `'finding'` the `i` character would be the first returned. I've made it so I generated this hash, now I just need to sort it so that the character that has the lowest index but the highest count will be first. Does anyone have an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Are you really wanting to sort, or just select the one value in the hash that is "optimum"?

Comment: the one value that is optimum. I need a way to get "i"=>[1, 2]

Comment: Do you want to preserve the hash structure or just get to the single letter that fits the criteria?

Comment: If I'm understanding your problem, you are trying to find the most frequent character in some string, and in the event of a tie, choose the character that comes first. Is that about right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Ruby `sort_by` block, Ruby can compare arrays, which is done in element order. In your case, you want reverse order by the second element of the array, then order by first element. So you can construct your sort block as follows:

```
arr = {"f"=>[0, 1], "i"=>[1, 2], "n"=>[2, 2], "d"=>[3, 1], "g"=>[6, 1]}

arr.sort_by { |a| [-a[1][1], a[1][0]] }.first
```

Ruby firsts converts `arr` to an array that looks like this:

```
[["f", [0, 1]], ["i", [1, 2]], ["n", [2, 2]], ["d", [3, 1]], ["g", [6, 1]]]
```

Then for each element that looks like `[letter, [position, count]]` (represented by the sort block argument, `a`), it is comparing `[-count, position]` for the sort.

This will give:

```
["i", [1,2]]
```

You can then do with that form whatever you wish.

---

Note, you can use `max_by ...` instead of `sort_by ... .first` in the above. I completely forgot about `max_by`, but Jörg W Mittag's nice answer reminded me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, there is no need to sort the hash at all to get the answer you are looking for, since you never actually need the sorted hash, you only need the maximum.

So, something like this should do the trick:

```rb
hash.max_by {|(_, (idx, frequency))| [frequency, -idx] }
#=> [?i, [1, 2]]
```

The entire thing would then look something like this:

```rb
str = 'Hello Nett'

str.
  each_char.
  with_index.
  each_with_object(Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = [0, nil]}) do |(char, idx), acc|
      next unless /\p{Alphabetic}/ === char
      char = char.downcase
      acc[char][1] ||= idx
      acc[char][0] += 1
    end.
max_by {|(_, (frequency, idx))| [frequency, -idx] }
#=> [?n, [2, 1]]
```